# how to have "Appendix" in title while using quotchap

Tags: latex

I am using the `quotchap` package in `book` document class. In the appendices, I need to have the "Appendix" term in the title before the alphabetical order of the appendix. For example, I need to have

> **Appendix A**
> Proof of Theorem 1

However, by using the following code, I will get something like this:

> **A**
> Proof of Theorem 1

Any idea on how to remedy the issue is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{quotchap}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello world!}

\appendix

\chapter{Proof of Theorem~1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one would redefine `\thechapter` to add such a prefix, but the font your packages uses is so large, that the result won't fit on the page. Instead you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{quotchap}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello world!}

\appendix
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{{\Huge Appendix }\thechapter}{}{}
\makeatother


\chapter{Proof of Theorem~1}

\end{document}
```